# Can the multer-s3 package be used with AWS v3 NodeJS SDK?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, multer-s3

The `multer-s3` npm package's documentation only covers the old AWS v2 API (`aws-sdk` and initialization in the code with `new aws.S3(options)`).

However, I am using the `@aws-sdk/client-s3` package; is there another package with similar functionality to `multer-s3` compatible? What (express-)middleware can be used to upload files to S3 storage with AWS v3 SDK?

Comment: Why can't you use the SDK directly?

Comment: Which SDK do you mean? The `aws-sdk` package is v2; we do only work with v3, so the new namespaced package.

Comment: What is preventing you to use the version2?

Comment: We have already a working setup with the new version and it would probably be quite a pain to use the older version; why should we ever downgrade if it is not absolutely necessary?